# automapper for ef6 list value

Tags: entity-framework, automapper

```
public class TestEntity
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Test
{
  public string name { get; set; }
}

List<TestEntity> testEntities;
List<Test> test;
testEntities= _db.testEntity.ToList();
```

How do I use `AutoMapper` to map the value from `testEntities` to `test` using EF6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is from one of my working projects, maybe this can help you. I am using Automapper 5.2.0.0

The case below is just to map two different classes

```
            var referenceInfo = service.GetReferenceNumber(criteria);

            var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
                cfg.CreateMap<ReferenceInfo, ReferenceInfoModel>();
            });

            var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
            var dest = mapper.Map<ReferenceInfo, ReferenceInfoModel>(referenceInfo);
```

if you want to create a map from a list or in my case IEnumerable it should be like

```
        IEnumerable<ReferenceInfo> entityList = bizService.GetReferenceList();

        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
            cfg.CreateMap<ReferenceInfo, ReferenceInfoModel>();
        });

        var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
        var dest = mapper.Map<IEnumerable<ReferenceInfo>, IEnumerable<ReferenceInfoModel>>(entityList);
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

In order to use Automapper you need to to install Automapper  . The create a static class and call it at application start method . (its optional step but for maintenance purpose you should have a class which have all mapping defined and then call it globally and then you can use it .)

then

```
public static class AutoMapperConfiguration
{
    public static void Configure()
    {
          Mapper.CreateMap<TestEntity, Test>().ReverseMap();
    }
}
```

then 
   to use it

```
 AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<TestEntity, Test>(entity);
```

for list use like this

```
   AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<List<TestEntity>,List< Test>>(entity);
```

in case you have different name of properties then you can use ForMember function and map them individual .
   for example

```
     Mapper.CreateMap<TestEntity, Test>()
     .ForMember(p => p.name, opt => 
      opt.MapFrom(src => src.Name));
```

and wise versa .

Comment: I use 'Name ' in TemplateEntity and 'name' in Template, does it has any impact?

Comment: you can manually configure property in case name is different  .I will add that in asnwer but it s very easy . If you need more help let me know

Comment: I updated my answer I hope noe my answer is complete :) I hope it will  be helpful for you and other  .

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, but 'CreateMap' is not working anymore.

Comment: And what error are you getting ? I have this thing implemented in my production aplication and it works fine .

Comment: AutoMapper.Mapper does not contain definition for CreateMap

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133703/discussion-between-yashveer-singh-and-alvin).